# Angular11 value set in service variable gets cleared for subsequent calls

Tags: rxjs, angular11

I wanted to do conditional http call and got the solution from [Angular 11 how to make one of the http request in higher order mapping conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75338219/angular-11-how-to-make-one-of-the-http-request-in-higher-order-mapping-condition)

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectGuidService {
    private projectsGuid = '';
  projectGuid$ = this.projectsGuid !== ''
                    ? of(this.projectsGuid)
                    : this.apiService.get('projects/latest').pipe(
                        map(({id}) => id),
                        tap(_ => console.log('current projectsGuid', this.projectsGuid)),
                        tap(guid => { console.log('tap project guid service', guid); this.projectsGuid = guid; })
                      );

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private appSettingsService: AppSettingsService
  )
  {
    console.log('project guid service');
    //this.projectsGuid = this.appSettingsService.settings.projectId ?? '';
  }

}
```

But in the above solution the http call is made even for the second time ie. even after the first time the value is set to this.projectsGuid.

Not sure what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the condition will be evaluated only one time.
you set `this.apiService.get('projects/latest')` in `projectGuid$` and alway subscribe to the same, without evaluating it again.
one way to solve your problem is to move the logic in a funcion:

```js
public projectGuid$():Observable<string>{
  return this.projectsGuid !== ''
                    ? of(this.projectsGuid)
                    : this.apiService.get('projects/latest').pipe(
                        map(({id}) => id),
                        tap(_ => console.log('current projectsGuid', this.projectsGuid)),
                        tap(guid => { console.log('tap project guid service', guid); this.projectsGuid = guid; })
                      );
}
```

and then you do `this.projectGuid$().subscribe()`. do not store the result in a variable as you did before.

Answer (score 0):

RxJs provides the `shareReplay` Operator that does exactlty what you're intending. It repeats the last given value of the Observable.

So if you change your Property declaration to :

```js
projectGuid$ = this.apiService.get('projects/latest').pipe(
    map(({ id }) => id),
    shareReplay(1)
);
```

The `this.apiService.get('projects/latest')` gets only called once, even for multiple Observers.